# PEPS mail, smtp able to send email externally but not receiving

Tags: email, nginx, docker, smtp, haraka

I'm currently trying to setup [PEPS](http://peps.in/) on my server, and having a problem receiving email sent from an external address.

I'm able to send and receive email internally fine, and i'm also able to send email externally, but I never receive email sent from an external address.

I can telnet in to port 25, but I get

```
connection to host lost
```

at the end of

```
HELO example.co.uk
MAIL FROM: address@other.co.uk
RCPT TO: aname@example.co.uk
DATA
Subject: Test
<ENTER>
test Message
.
```

After i've typed the '.' I instantly get the `connection to host lost` message

---

My servers setup using nginx, with multiple sub-domains, i've got PEPS running on mail.example.co.uk via a reverse proxy, and that bit works fine.

Comment: Did you progress this ?   it seems out of the box PEPS is outgoing email only